# Windows 10 login screen has wrong email address

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

I have a Windows 10 HP laptop and the login screen has an email displaying `gmial` instead of `gmail`. 
If I use the forgot password link, it sends the code to the correct email, so all the setup info is correct.

How do I change the email displayed on the screen, so I can use my correct password?

Comment: Unlink the account from the Microsoft Account, allow Windows to create a new user profile, delete the old profile directory and link your account again.

Answer (score 0):

See if this gets you to a place where you can edit the name:

If I am understanding your issue - the display name can be changed from User Accounts Control Panel for local accounts -

Press WIN key and R - enter "lusrmgr.msc" without the quotes. 
Click Users on left side - the User Name in the middle and look for "more actions" on the right.